# Error con una consulta mySql

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta con mySql pero el resultado no es el esperado ya que se repiten filas y algunos datos no tienen relación alguna.

Necesito seleccionar de la tabla `list_task` el `NAME` y el `PUBLIC_NUMBER` y de la tabla `list_project` el `NAME` y el `PUBLIC_NUMBER` que hace referencia a un usuario X.

Entonces, cada proyecto (`list_project`) tiene cero o muchas columnas (`list_column`) y cada columna tiene cero o muchas tareas (`list_task`). Un usuario puede crear proyectos(`ADMIN_USER`), columnas (`USER_ID`) y tareas (`USER_ID`). La tabla `list_myprojects` almacena todos los proyectos a los que un usuario tiene acceso, mientras que la tabla `list_projects` almacena solo la información del proyecto.

[image: Tablas de la base de datos]

La consulta que había creado es esta:

```
SELECT list_task.PUBLIC_NUMBER AS TASK_NUMBER, list_task.NAME AS TASK_NAME, list_project.NAME AS PROJECT_NAME, list_project.PUBLIC_NUMBER AS PROJECT_NUMBER
FROM list_task 
JOIN list_myprojects ON list_myprojects.USER_ID = list_task.USER_ID 
JOIN list_project ON list_myprojects.PUBLIC_NUMBER = list_project.PUBLIC_NUMBER 
WHERE list_task.COLUMN_NUMBER IN 
    (SELECT list_column.PUBLIC_NUMBER 
     FROM list_column 
     JOIN list_myprojects ON list_column.PROJECT_ID = list_myprojects.PUBLIC_NUMBER 
     WHERE list_myprojects.USER_ID = 'R8D0F1Z6h6W5K9g8n4U5' ) 
AND list_myprojects.USER_ID = 'R8D0F1Z6h6W5K9g8n4U5'
```

Como se puede ver en la imagen siguiente los resultados salen duplicados y mal ya que un mismo `TASK_NUMBER` pertenece a dos  `PROJECT_NUMBER` distintos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me haya explicado bien

Comment: Esas líneas que se cruzan en tu diseño me hacen pensar que posiblemente necesites una tabla que gestione las relaciones entre algunas de tus tablas... Será útil para una posible respuestas, que mostrases el resultado final que quieres obtener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que tu esquema no está bien diseñado por cuatro razones

1. Las tablas tienen nombres que llaman a confusión (`list_r` no hay cómo saber que se refiere a las entidades de usuario)
2. Las tablas parecieran tener una llave primaria `INTERN_NUMBER` que no siempre identifica a la entidad, sino que ésta en algunos casos se identifica via `PUBLIC_NUMBER`. Todas las entidades debiesen identificarse con su `INTERN_NUMBER`.
3. Las columnas que relacionan entidades tienen nombres confusos. (`list_myprojects.PUBLIC_NUMBER` debiera ser al menos `list_myprojects.PROJECT_NUMBER`)
4. Si un usuario puede tener acceso a un proyecto creado por otro, cuyas columnas fueron creadas potencialmente por otros, y de entre cuyas tareas algunas pueden haber sido creadas por otros, no tienes integridad relacional a través de los `USER_ID` y ese campo debiera ser sólo referencial.

Imagino que heredaste este esquema como viene y ya no hay nada que hacer, pero con esas condiciones es difícil entender qué hace la query. Dicho esto, me parece que la planteas mal al hacer `JOIN` entre `list_myprojects` y `list_task` en un comienzo, considerando que quieres listar el **acceso** a otras entidades y no la **autoría** de la entidad (que parece ser el significado de `list_task.USER_ID`).

Yo plantearía la consulta como:

```
Tráeme todos los elementos de `list_myprojects` del usuario `R8D0F1Z6h6W5K9g8n4U5` 
  Y de esta tabla sus proyectos relacionados
    Y de éstos sus columnas relacionadas
      Y de éstas sus tareas relacionadas
```

Esto sería

```
SELECT t.PUBLIC_NUMBER AS TASK_NUMBER, 
       t.NAME AS TASK_NAME, 
       p.NAME AS PROJECT_NAME, 
       p.PUBLIC_NUMBER AS PROJECT_NUMBER
FROM list_myprojects mp
JOIN list_project p ON p.PUBLIC_NUMBER = mp.PUBLIC_NUMBER
LEFT JOIN list_column c ON c.PROJECT_ID = p.PUBLIC_NUMBER 
LEFT JOIN list_task t ON t.COLUMN_NUMBER = c.PUBLIC_NUMBER       
WHERE mp.USER_ID = 'R8D0F1Z6h6W5K9g8n4U5'
```

Y ésto sólo funcionará si `list_project.PUBLIC_NUMBER` , `list_column.PUBLIC_NUMBER` y `list_task.PUBLIC_NUMBER` son llaves únicas.

En la práctica esto también debiese incluir llaves foráneas

- `list_column.PROJECT_ID` referenciando `list_project.PUBLIC_NUMBER`
- `list_task.COLUMN_NUMBER` referenciando `list_column.PUBLIC_NUMBER`
- `list_myprojects.PUBLIC_NUMBER` referenciando `list_project.PUBLIC_NUMBER`
- `list_myprojects.USER_ID` referenciando `list_r.INTERN_NUMBER`

Comment: La consulta funciona perfectamente, aun así modificare la base de datos con los 4 puntos que has dicho